# replace json string using regex in PHP

Tags: php, json, regex

How can i replace/remove some string in this JSON ?.I think this problem can be solve using str_replace method or preg_replace 
but i don't know how to add the regex

Please help me.

here my json

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [DESC] => bla bal bal
                    [SOLD] => 0
                    [contact_no] => 1234
                    [title] =>  Hiiiii
                    [price] => 10900
                    [big_image] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/14.jpg
                            [1] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/15.jpg
                        )

                    [small_image] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/small/14.jpg
                            [1] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/small/15.jpg
                        )

                [tpe] => user
            )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [DESC] => fo fo fof ofof
                    [SOLD] => 0
                    [contact_no] => 234522
                    [title] => Hellooooo sddf
                    [price] => 0
                    [big_image] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/154.jpg
                            [1] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/144.jpg
                            [2] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/147.jpg
                        )

                     [small_image] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/small/154.jpg
                            [1] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/small/144.jpg
                            [2] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/small/147.jpg
                        )

                    [tpe] => user
                )

        )

    [pis] => 3
    [totals] => 23
    [curpage] => 1
    [total_ads] => 71
)
```

will i use this function to export the json to csv

```
function array_flatten ($nonFlat) {
    $flat = array();
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new RecursiveArrayIterator($nonFlat)) as $k=>$v) {
        $flat[$k] = $v;
    }
    return $flat;
}

$fp = fopen("output.csv","w");
foreach ($json['data'] as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, array_flatten($fields));
}
fclose($fp);
```

the above code work fine but each image link is have one column so looks like bad , i need to make each group of pics on one column
 I try to add regex to part of link images except the first image url [0] and merge the other with it , that i can putting them together in one column....
so for the experiment i add this to the above code but seems nothing happen

```
 $flat[$k] = str_replace('[1-7] => http', "http", $v);
```

here i expect the output something like that

```
....
[big_image] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/154.jpg
                            http://example.com/images/user_adv/144.jpg
                            http://example.com/images/user_adv/147.jpg
                        )

                    [small_image] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/small/154.jpg
                            http://example.com/images/user_adv/small/144.jpg
                            http://example.com/images/user_adv/small/147.jpg
                        )
.....
```

edit this the .csv file output look like this

[image: this]

and I'm looking to be something like that

[image: this the s]

Comment: change  `$flat[$k] = $v;` to  `$flat[$k] = is_array($v)?implode(' ',$v):$v;`, if i get you right

Comment: I've add but does do any change

Comment: i think i dont  get `will i use this function to export the json to csv` , because you do open and csv and convert it in your code?

Comment: may add the unexpect outptut

Comment: I've edit my question and add the screenshot  for csv file output and the expect  , btw I've not put the complete code but the json data i got it from online source then decode it and convert it to csv.

Answer (score 1):

ok I've fixed by

```
foreach (
    new RecursiveArrayIterator($nonFlat) as $k=>$v) {
 $flat[$k] = is_array($v)?implode(" ",$v):$v;
```

now i got each group of images on one column

thanks :)